# swagger-express-middleware : Cleaner validation message

Tags: javascript, validation, express, swagger, middleware

I'm currently using [`swagger-express-middleware`](https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-express-middleware) package to validate the requests against my Swagger API document.

Following [their document](https://apidevtools.org/swagger-express-middleware/docs/middleware/validateRequest.html), I have implemented the middleware and handled the error as shown below

```
createMiddleware(swaggerDoc, app, (middlewareError, middleware) => {
    app.use(middleware.metadata());
    app.use(middleware.parseRequest());
    app.use(middleware.validateRequest());

    // Error handler to send the swagger validation response
    app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(err.status).json({
            type: 'SCHEMA VALIDATION FAILED',
            message: err.message
        });
    });
});
```

If any error in the schema, the response I get back from the middleware has a property `message` with description of the error which is obviously an important part of the response as it tells the requester whats missing. Unfortunately though, the `message` content is not very intuitive or readable. For example if a property is missing from the request the description would be

```
"message": "The \"pinDetails\" body parameter is invalid ({\"Pindd\":\"asd\"}) \nJSON Schema validation error. \nData path: \"\" \nSchema path: \"/required/0\" \nMissing required property: pin"
```

As you can see the message is not very intuitive and clean which makes it hard to read. So, my question is, does the package provide any way to get back a cleaner version of the message or any other way I can do the same ?

> Note: Since the message is multi-line and most importantly **dynamic**, I cant just split or replace the strings or it would look like some unrelated sentences put together (maybe worse case that's what I would do ultimately but definitely not what I would prefer).

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue in `swagger-express-middleware` and based on the reply(quoted below), it seems like for now there is no way (except maybe using `dataPath` and `schemaPath`) to output a more user-friendly message.

Link to the issue: https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-express-middleware/issues/120

Response from the developer for this issue:

> Yeah, I agree that the error messages aren't very user-friendly or easy to parse. The errors [ultimately come from tv4](https://github.com/APIDevTools/swagger-express-middleware/blob/9d19da25f83d46c69628a4fe9dc461de98f272cf/lib/helpers/json-schema.js#L201-L213), which is the JSON Schema validator that I use under the hood. TV4 adds a few helpful properties to its Error objects, such as dataPath and schemaPath, which may help you construct a more user-friendly message. In the future, I plan to switch to [Z-Schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/z-schema), which has better error messages and adds much more helpful properties to the Error objects, which makes it **much** easier to construct user-friendly messages.

So, for now I just replaced all the `\` and `\n` with `.` to make it more readable. Then I replaced all the `"` with `'` to make sure the string is valid. Like so,

```
 res.status(err.status).json({
     type: 'SCHEMA VALIDATION FAILED',
     message: err.message.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '.').replace(/"/g, '\'')
 });
```

Obviously not a full-proof solution but that's an improvement for now. The response would look like:

```
"message": "The 'pinDetails' body parameter is invalid ({'Pindd':'asd'}) .JSON Schema validation error. .Data path: '' .Schema path: '/required/0' .Missing required property: pin"
```

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant for you, but in a REST API I built with express, I used the wonderful Joi package from hapi for schema definition and request validation. I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validation to easily invoke Joi schema validations from express route handlers. Then I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi-to-swagger to convert my joi schema to swagger. With this, I am able to provide full Swagger UI documentation for my API, but with the beautiful validations and error messages of Joi.